# "The application could not be installed because the installer file is damaged." only on some machines

Tags: air, certificate

Some people are having trouble installing my AIR app. Most are installing it fine.

Some of the people having trouble are installing it for the first time, others as an update.

I've tried two versions of the installer - one with a migrated cert, the other without migration.

Also, I've gone through these steps with them:

- check that your computer's system clock is correct. Correct the date and time if it not current.
- make sure you have the latest updates for your machine eg latest Windows updates for Windows machines
- install the latest version of the Adobe AIR runtime (download from http://get.adobe.com/air)
- uninstall my app if it is already installed
- make sure the application folder does not exist (in, for example, c:\Program Files or c:\Program Files (x86)). If it does exist, delete it.
- empty the Trash (Mac OS) or Recycle Bin (Windows)
- try installing my app again

I'm wondering if there are any other steps that you are aware of to test?

Cheers